# regex? - str find? - c++ - windows 7 - try to answer on pong irc

Tags: c++, windows

I have a string ( answer from irc server).

From this string i need to get integer, to answer (PONG number_from_sv)

```
some txt PING :i_need_this_numbers some_text
```

How to get this numbers near "PING :", i dont know how long it is. I only know, that is a numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Using the c++11 standard you can find the ID with built-in regex.

One possible regular expression is `PING :(\\d+)`, where \d masks an arbitrary digit.
The `+` means greater than or equal to 1 (number of digits).

A small script finding the ID could look like this

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>    

using namespace std;



int main ()
{
    std::string s ("some txt PING :665454 some_text");
    std::smatch mt;
    std::regex r ("PING :(\\d+) ");

    if (std::regex_search ( s, mt, r))
    {
        smatch::iterator it = mt.begin()+1; // First match is entire s
        cout<<"Your ping ID is: "<<*it<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: regex r ("PING :(\\d*) "); -- return error but not as compiler (in program - console)

regex r ("PING :(\d*) "); - this dont return, but it don't working.

Comment: What error was returned? What compiler do you use? Does it provide the c++11 standard?

Comment: dev c++ dev 5.4.1 error: terminate called after throwing an instance of "std::regex_error" what<>: regex_error - and compiler gcc 4/.7.1

Comment: Well it seems to be a matter with the used grammar. The compiler I used (clang) has ECMAScript as default grammar and there \d stands for a digit. g++ probably uses a basic POSIX grammar where `\d` stands for what ever...

Please try to replace `\\d` by `[[:d:]]`.

Comment: What's about this:
`std::regex r("PING :([[:d:]]+) ", regex_constants::ECMAScript);`?

If there is still an error catch it and post the result of what().

Comment: 21,41,13 - value from other printf. http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/4599/etys.png

Comment: hmm, maybe my class is badly?

 std::regex r ("PING :(.*) "); - no error but dont working mhm

Comment: Due to g++ 4.7.1's [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.1/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011) it actually does not completely support regex features, see section 28 in corresponding table. Now you can either update gcc to 4.8.x (full support) or try to use an extended POSIX grammar with `std::regex r("PING :(.*) ", regex_constants::extended);`.

Comment: mhm dev c++ still have tdm-gcc in 4.7.1 version. I update my dev c++ from 5.4.1 to 5.5.1 and we see

Comment: I dont want to change my compiler (i want dev - c++) maybe, is there a man who dont have problem the same as me?

Best Regards...